# Snow Leopard mounts NTFS disk read-only

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, ntfs, mount

I can not mount my NTFS disk read-write. I tried ntfsMounter as well as this command:

```
$ sudo mount_ntfs -o rw /dev/disk1s1 foo
```

But they mount as read only:

```
$ sudo mount
/dev/disk1s1 on /Users/foo/bar (ntfs, local, read-only, noowners)
```

The weird part is that it worked some time ago. But then it just stopped working. I've even tried to format the disk again with no result...

I also have a friend with the exact same disk and mounting that will result in both read and write access.

Is there some weird cache I can release or something?

Comment: Nobody seems to have directly addressed this in their answers so I'll add it here: Mac OS X does not ship with a read/write NTFS driver. The one bundled is read-only, so what you're experiencing is normal. As both answers say, you can install another NTFS driver that does support read and write.

Answer (score 1):

Try using NTFS-3G. It's a free open-source engine to read and write NTFS drives. Once it's installed, you can mount just by connecting the drive to the computer, and NTFS-3G will take over

Answer (score 0):

Note that Tuxera started charging the binary distribution of the latest ntfs-3g. The older version on their [blog](http://macntfs-3g.blogspot.com/) is not compatible with 64-bit kernel or Lion. (You can install it, but it won't mount anything.)

You can however, compile it from [source](http://www.tuxera.com/community/ntfs-3g-download/). It's all packed up for you, so all you have to do is to install Xcode 4 and copy and paste 3 commands.